# How do I remove Firebase event listeners if I am adding them using a separate utils class's static method?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a Forum application in which I have to write the same code such as adding listeners to Firebase references, binding data to views etc at a lot of places. So I wrote a Utils class with methods for all such repeated codes.

```
public class UIUtils {
    public static FirebaseDatabase mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    public static DatabaseReference mReference = mDatabase.getReference();

    public static class DataBindingUtils {
        public static void bindDataToFollowButton(final RecyclerViewHolder.UnansweredRecyclerViewHolder
                                                          holder, String questionKey, final String userName) {
            mReference.child("Posts").
                    child(questionKey).child("Followers")
                    .addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                if (dataSnapshot.getValue().equals(userName)) {
                                    holder.FollowButton.setChecked(true);
                                }
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                                Log.v("onChildRemoved", dataSnapshot.toString());
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                        }
                    });

        }
```

How do I remove such listeners as in the above method?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

Defining the listener

```
private ChildEventListener mListener = new ChildEventListener() {
    //Your Implementation of Listener
}
```

Adding the Listener to a DatabaseReference:

```
mReference.addChildEventListener(mListener);
```

Removing the Listener from the DatabaseReference:

```
mReference.removeEventListener(mListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

To solve this, I recommend you use the following method that can be created it in your `UIUtils` class:

```
public static void removeListener(Map<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> map) {
    for (Map.Entry<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = entry.getKey();
        ValueEventListener valueEventListener = entry.getValue();
        databaseReference.removeEventListener(valueEventListener);
    }
}
```

In your activity class where youn need to remove one or more listeners, just create a `Map` and put all references and the listeners you want to remove. Your Map should look like this:

```
Map<DatabaseReference, ValueEventListener> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put(referenceOne, listenerOne);
map.put(referenceTwo, listenerTwo);
//You can add as many listeners as you want
```

And then just call the `removeListener` method from your `UIUtils` class and pass the `map` object as an argument like this:

```
UIUtils.removeListener(map);
```